# Can Websphere automatically remove temporary files?

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, birt, maximo

I am currently using Websphere to host IBM Maximo, when a BIRT report is created and emailed, Websphere stores this in its temporary files. These files are often very large and are taking up a lot of disk space.

Does anyone know of a setting in Websphere/Maximo/BIRT that remove these.

Websphere - 6.1
Maximo - 7.1
BIRT - 2.3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a setting, but you can set up a cron task in Linux to remove files that have aged beyond your desired time:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/

```
   find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

The above statement will erase files older than five days.